# How to make a global function for rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Can somebody pls tell me how to make a function accessible to all, regardless if its a controller, model, helper, or view will call it. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your config/application.rb:

```
Dir.glob("./lib/*.{rb}").each { |file| require file } # require each file from lib directory
```

then just create .rb file with all you need and put it to your /lib directory